# jQuery draggable outside of browser

Tags: jquery, draggable

Currently, without using jQuery it is possible to drag an image from your browser onto your desktop (firefox, chrome, safari).  I'd like to achieve the same thing using jQuery draggable.  Currently, if I try dragging a 'draggable' element, the element disappears when it leaves the browser window.

Any ideas if this is possible, if so how?

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible to my knowledge. That would be a heck of a security threat if it were.

Comment: yeah, it's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar discussion with respect to images:

[Is it possible to Drag-and-Drop images between Web sites (applications)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308328/is-it-possible-to-drag-and-drop-images-between-web-sites-applications)