# Kendo UI Window asp.net mvc3

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where I have to display more than 10 **Kendo UI Windows** in a page . I should able to drag the windows in the page anywhere on the desktop and also in extended monitor . I know the scope of the window is within the page. But how can I make achieve this in asp.net mvc3  ?

Comment: You can render as many windows as you want looping through dynamic content (I prefer partial views). Can you show some code on what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I agree, I can create as many I want. But my question is whether I can  drag the window and drop them anywhere on the desktop. I couldn`t able to drag the window outside the browser page.

Comment: I think this is not possible, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566371/jquery-draggable-outside-of-browser